# Search most common phrases by part of phrase

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, search-engine, sphinx

I have not trivial task and want to understand if Sphinx or Solr is right instrument to solve it . Simplified example: i have search field on my site for searching by product description. and next descriptions in mysql db:

```
Id  Desc
1   this is my test document number one. also checking search within phrases.
2   this is my test document number two
3   this is another group
4   this is first group
5   this is first test
6   this is your test
```

When user type some text in search field ex. "is" he should get next results(top three phrases which contains "is"):
"this is", "is my", "is first".

Is someone has any ideas how to do that ? Maybe you now some better search engine that can fit my needs ?

```
<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="text_auto">
<analyzer type="index"> 
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/> 
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/> 
    <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="4" outputUnigrams="true" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="false" /> 
</analyzer> 
<analyzer type="query"> 
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/> 
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/> 
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/> 
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/> 
</analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="title" type="text_auto" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
<field name="content_autosuggest" type="text_auto" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

<copyField source="title" dest="content_autosuggest"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a [ShingleFilter](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ShingleFilterFactory). As shown in the example on the wiki, if you set both maxShingleSize and mixShingleSize to 2, you get this:

```
this is my test document => this is, is my, my test, test document
```

(Make sure to use an appropriate tokenizer and other analyzers, if required, prior to the shingle filter.)

Then you can do a regex search like this on this field:

```
shingle_field:/(is .*)|(.* is)/
```

which should return all the documents. (I believe this should work, since the wiki states: *it creates combinations of tokens as a single token*.)

Use a [facet query](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters) to get the counts:

```
shingle_field:/(is .*)|(.* is)/&facet=true&facet.field=shingle_field
```

(Add `rows=0`, if you do not care about the documents and need only the facets.)

Comment: Thanks Arun. Will try this Filter

Comment: Looks like facet query search only by prefix. Ex. when I try to find "is" it doesn't return "this is".

Comment: Update your qn with the fieldType for the field you have defined.

Comment: What do you mean "Update your qn with the fieldType" ? Could you show simple example ?

Comment: What is the fieldType definition for the field you are using to do the query and faceting on?